# Рекурсивный запрос в MS SQL, в чем ошибка?

Tags: рекурсия, sql-server, sql

Имеется рекурсивный запрос. По условиям задачи необходимо вывести иерархическую структуру имя, уровень в иерархии и кол-во подчинённых. Данный запрос выдает мне одну строку (верх дерева) с parent_id равный NULL. Как вывести всю таблицу в нужном формате?

```
WITH
    Rec (id, parent_id, name, level)
AS (
        SELECT e.id, e.parent_id, e.name, 0 AS level
        FROM Employee e
        UNION ALL
            SELECT e.id, e.parent_id, e.name, Rec.level+1 AS level
            FROM Employee e
            JOIN Rec ON Rec.id = e.parent_id 
    )
SELECT Rec.*, COUNT = (
        SELECT COUNT(*) 
        FROM Employee e 
        WHERE e.id = Rec.id
    )
FROM Rec
WHERE Rec.parent_id IS NULL;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> WHERE Rec.parent_id IS NULL;

Видимо, это условие для корня. Оттого и выводит только его. Это условие нужно поместить в анкорную часть, и от него уже раскручивать.